# Flux ajax api calls in stores return to parent function

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm calling to my api by using the following:

```
    getBall: function(){
    ball = xhttp({
        url: '/current',
        method: 'get'
    }).then(function(data){
        return data;
    })

    return ball;
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to access `data` in the parent function. I tried assigning the variable `ball` (a promise object), but it never lets me access `data`.

I want to return the value of `data` to the parent function (`getBall`).  What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: It's a promise. Why doesn't `getBall().then( data => /* ... */ )` work?

Answer (score 1):

The `getBall` function has most likely exited **before** the xhttp request has completed. So there's no way pass `data` back into `getBall`. The best you can do is attach additional `.then` clauses to `ball`, or pass `ball` as a promise to the caller of `getBall`.  The caller can attach its own `.then` clauses.

An alternative is to use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), but that and all other async methods such as Promises (or even simple callbacks) require thinking beyond the traditional imperative model.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. it does exit `getBall` before `xhttp` has completed. The goal of this function is to simply return the data from the ajax call. with that said, what is the simplest way to achieve this...removing the promise?